# React Native: require() with Dynamic String?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, require

I have read several posts about issues that people are having with React Native and the `require()` function when trying to require a dynamic resource such as:

Dynamic **(fails)**:

```
urlName = "sampleData.json";
data = require('../' + urlName);
```

vs. Static **(succeeds)**:

```
data = require('../sampleData.json');
```

I have read on some threads that this is a bug in React Native and in others that this is a feature.

Is there a new way to require a dynamic resource within a function?

Related Posts (all fairly old in React time):

- [Importing Text from local json file in React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085341/importing-text-from-local-json-file-in-react-native)
- [React Native - Dynamically List/Require Files In Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901584/react-native-dynamically-list-require-files-in-directory)
- [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)
- [React Native: how to use require(path) with dynamic urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516269/react-native-how-to-use-requirepath-with-dynamic-urls)

Answer (score 43):

As i have heard of, react's `require()` only uses static url not variables, that means that you have to do `require('/path/file')`, take a look at this [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7015#issuecomment-217390058) and [this one](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481) for more alternative solutions, there are a couple of other ways to do it!
for e.g

```
const images = {
profile: {
    profile: require('./profile/profile.png'),
    comments: require('./profile/comments.png'),
},
   image1: require('./image1.jpg'),
   image2: require('./image2.jpg'),
};

export default images;
```

then

```
import Images from './img/index';

render() {
    <Image source={Images.profile.comments} />
}
```

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907218/react-native-use-variable-for-image-file)

Comment: Well that sucks, I want to retrieve the image source from firebase and I can't do it dynamically. So now I have to use cloud storage and there goes my full offline support

Comment: Hey @MartínSchere did you found any other option beside using cloud storage? Now I'm facing same issue like yours, using import images one by one solution quite redundant for me..

Comment: @metalheadcoder there is no way around it, i just created a big json file for them

Answer (score 21):

Here is my solution.

**Setup**

File structure:

```
app  
  |--src
    |--assets
      |--images
        |--logos
          |--small_kl_logo.png
          |--small_a1_logo.png
          |--small_kc_logo.png
          |--small_nv_logo.png
          |--small_other_logo.png

        |--index.js
    |--SearchableList.js
```

In `index.js`, I have this:

```
const images = {
  logos: {
    kl: require('./logos/small_kl_logo.png'),
    a1: require('./logos/small_a1_logo.png'),
    kc: require('./logos/small_kc_logo.png'),
    nv: require('./logos/small_nv_logo.png'),
    other: require('./logos/small_other_logo.png'),
  }
};

export default images;
```

In my `SearchableList.js` component, I then imported the Images component like this:

```
import Images from './assets/images';
```

I then created a new function `imageSelect` in my component:

```
imageSelect = network => {
  if (network === null) {
    return Images.logos.other;
  }

  const networkArray = {
    'KL': Images.logos.kl,
    'A1': Images.logos.a1,
    'KC': Images.logos.kc,
    'NV': Images.logos.nv,
    'Other': Images.logos.other,
  };

  return networkArray[network];
};
```

Then in my components `render` function I call this new `imageSelect` function to dynamically assign the desired Image based on the value in the `this.state.network`:

```
render() {
  <Image source={this.imageSelect(this.state.network)} />
}
```

The value passed into the imageSelect function could be any dynamic string. I just chose to have it set in the state first and then passed in.

I hope this answer helps. :)

Comment: Thanks! this is the best approach for multiple images. In my case, I had also to add '.default' at the end of 'require("..")'.

Comment: thank you brother, it helped me ! i forgot to add require inside the list of dictionaries images key's path

Answer (score 4):

I have found that a dynamic path for `require()` works when it starts with a static string. For example `require("./" + path)` works, whereas `require(path)` doesn't.

Comment: I've tried this before, it works like a charm in React (with CRA/Gatsby/NextJS), but not in React Native. Have you actually been able use this in React Native as well? Were there any other configurations like in `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json` or `babal.config.js`?

Comment: Man, thank you so much, this one works for me! I'm on React though, not React Native

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this that cannot work with the existing answers, I have an alternative.

First I'll explain my scenario.  We have a mono repo with a number of packages (large react-native app).  I want to dynamically import a bunch of locale files for i18n without having to keep a central registry in some magic file. There could be a number of teams working in the same monorepo and the DX we want is for package developers to be able to just add their local files in a known folder `{{packageName}}/locales/en.json` and have our core i18n functionality pick up their strings.

After several less than ideal solutions, I finally landed on https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-preval as an ideal solution for us.  This is how I did it:

```
const packageEnFiles = preval`
  const fs = require('fs');
  const path = require('path');

  const paths = [];

  const pathToPackages = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../packages/');
fs.readdirSync(pathToPackages)
    .filter(name => fs.lstatSync(path.join(pathToPackages, name)).isDirectory())
    .forEach(dir => {
      if (fs.readdirSync(path.join(pathToPackages, dir)).find(name => name === 'locales')) {
        const rawContents = fs.readFileSync(path.join(pathToPackages, dir, 'locales/en.json'), 'utf8');
        paths.push({
          name: dir,
          contents: JSON.parse(rawContents),
        });
      }
    });

  module.exports = paths;
`;
```

Then I can just iterate over this list and add the local files to i18next:

```
packageEnFiles.forEach(file => {
  i18n.addResourceBundle('en', file.name, file.contents);
});
```

Comment: Why not using [i18next-fs-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-fs-backend)?

Comment: Because I don't have node available at runtime in a react-native app, but babel does at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to switch between multiple locally stored images, you can also use this way:

```
        var titleImg;
        var textColor;
        switch (this.props.data.title) {
        case 'Футбол':
            titleImg = require('../res/soccer.png');
            textColor = '#76a963';
            break;
        case 'Баскетбол':
            titleImg = require('../res/basketball.png');
            textColor = '#d47b19';
            break;
        case 'Хоккей':
            titleImg = require('../res/hockey.png');
            textColor = '#3381d0';
            break;
        case 'Теннис':
            titleImg = require('../res/tennis.png');
            textColor = '#d6b031';
            break;
        }
```

In this snippet I change variables `titleImg` and `textColor` depending of the prop. I have put this snippet directly in `render()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Simple to dynamic images (using require)

Example array(into state)

```
this.state={
       newimage: require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room.png'),
       randomImages=[
         {
            image:require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room.png')
          },
         {
            image:require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room2.png')
          }
        ,
         {
            image:require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room3.png')
          }
        
        
        ]

}
```

Trigger image( like when press button(i select image random number betwenn 0-2))

```
let setImage=>(){

this.setState({newimage:this.state.randomImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
})
}
```

view

```
<Image
        style={{  width: 30, height: 30 ,zIndex: 500 }}
        
        source={this.state.newimage}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey lads I rounded another way to require It's ugly but works. Images dynamically. Instead of storing your URL in the state you store the entire JSX. For an example:

```
state = {
  image: []
};
```

Instead of

```
let imageURL = `'../assets/myImage.png'`
this.state.image = imageURL
```

You use

```
let greatImage = (<Image source={require(../assets/myImage.png)}></Image>)
this.state.image = greatImage
```

To render in the JSX

```
{this.state.image}
```

You can style your image in the variable too. I had to use some if statements to render some images dynamically and after break my head for 2 hours this was the way that solved my problem. Like I said It's ugly and probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution mentioned in [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481#issuecomment-264762855) thread for Android. This solves the issue but unfortunately, it's only for android.

But make sure to run `react-native run-android` after every update. Else, the added images won't appear in the app.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a module bundler like webpack?

If so, you can try `require.ensure()`

See: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: What if you are using vanilla React Native without a module bundler?

Comment: I think RN uses the metro bundler which is what doesn't seem to support dynamic require().

Answer (score -1):

Reading through the docs, I've found a working answer and I'm able to use dynamic images, in the docs they refer to it as Network Images here

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-images

Not sure if this can be applied to other file types, but as they list require with non image types

You would need to use the uri: call

```
data = {uri: urlName}
```

For me I got images working dynamically with this

```
<Image source={{uri: image}} />
```

Answer (score -2):

This seems to work  :

```html
const {
      messages,
    } = require(`../${dynamicPath}/messages.specific`);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).