# wants to set image URL by using state in react native

Tags: react-native

hi i am setting my state in componentdidmount life cycle..but in image url nothing is setting but when i alert it gives my url here is my code where in setting state..

```
componentDidMount(){
ls.get("savedata").then(data => { this.setState({ name: data.user.name },()=>{alert(this.state.name)}); });
ls.get("savedata").then(data => { this.setState({ image: data.user.profile_photo },()=>alert(this.state.image)); });
    }
```

here is view where in using image component

```
          <Image source={{uri:this.state.image}}style={{width: 130, height: 110}}
```

Comment: Are you using and url www.google.com/cat.png or a reference to a local file ? 
Try to put a condition before your image to see if there is a kind of race condition.
{this.state.image && <Image.../>}

Comment: i am getting image url from api and save into local storage and trying to show another page view

Comment: could you show us the image url please.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little bit of code for you and this example is working. You can try it in expo. I hope that will help you :) 
I chained the Image container with two images, one after an other.

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg"}, () =>{
      this.setState({image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg"})
    } );
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.image ?
        <Image source={{uri: this.state.image}} style={{width: 130, height:110}}/>
        : 
        null
      }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i need only ane pic which is save in local storage when user login ..but here i used  your method but nothing happens

Comment: Ok so if you have download your image before, you need to use require() now and not {uri:"http://someurl"}. 
Do you try with my real urls like mine, to now if that is not a css problem ? 
And can you put more code, and the result of your alert please

Answer (score 0):

**For Static Image Resources**

React Native provides a unified way of managing images and other media assets in your iOS and Android apps. To add a static image to your app, place it somewhere in your source code tree and reference it like this:

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image is stored locally then the `Image` tag should look like this:

```
    <Image
      style={styles.stretch}
      source={require(this.state.image)}
    />
```

Comment: You cannot do this, as react-native doesn't support [dynamic requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991669/react-native-require-with-dynamic-string).