# 500 Error on Image Source with dynamic resource react native

Tags: react-native

I get 500 error while using dynamic resource to display an image.
`<Image style={styles.image} source={require('../component/images/react-native.png')} />`
`<Image style={styles.image} source={require(article.imageUrl)} />`

"article.imageUrl" has exactly same value as first text.

react: 16.6.3

react-native: 0.58.4

Comment: You can’t use dynamic variables when using require. You have to use the exact value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: require() with Dynamic String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991669/react-native-require-with-dynamic-string)

Comment: I have a json list with image path how can I show this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of article.imageUrl="../component/images/react-native.png" , change it to:

```
article.imageUrl=require("../component/images/react-native.png");
```

and then:

```
source={article.imageUrl}
```

Because as Andrew commented, you can't use dynamic variales with require.