# react-native bundling failed Invalid call error when using 3rd party library

Tags: react-native

I wrote a React app which used a 3rd party library and had no issues.  I am now trying to write the equivalent app in React-Native (as a learning exercise) and I am running into an error as soon as I try and call an API in the 3rd party library.

I am on a windows machine and have react versions

- "react": "16.9.0",
- "react-native": "0.61.5",

**Error**

The error I am seeing in the window showing the metro builder has

```
error: bundling failed: src\scripts\my3rdPartyLib.js: src\scripts\my3rdPartyLib.js:Invalid call at line 121: 
require([something], function (....
```

In my Android emulator I am seeing

```
The development server returned response error code : 500
```

*Note: It also fails if i have the library coming from node-modules as apposed to copying it into my "scripts" folder.*

**What I have tried**

As per a thread on SO i uninstalled babel-preset-react-native and then installed it.

```
npm un -D babel-preset-react-native
npm i -D babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

Afterwards I realised as I am on version 61 it uses "metro-react-native-babel-preset", my babel.config.js contains the following

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the use of the 3rd party library working in my react-native app?

Answer (score 0):

After Googling, it is my understanding that React Native uses the metro bundler which doesn't seem to support dynamic require().

- https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/52
- [React Native: require() with Dynamic String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991669/react-native-require-with-dynamic-string)

Further investigation into the library that i am trying to use, i see that it is expecting to either be run in the browser or a Node environment.  For ReactNative this is not the case, therefore I believe I can not use this library in my application.