# Image Require Module using Dynamic Names in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**What I'm trying to do**

I wanna write `mCategories's on` in `require` in `source` of Image tag.

**Code**

```js
const mCategories = [
  {
    id: 1, name: 'All', off: 'all_on', on: 'all_on',
  }, {
    id: 2, name: 'Whole Cakes', off: 'wc', on: 'wc_on',
  },
  {
    id: 3, name: 'Sliced Cakes', off: 'sc', on: 'sc_on',
  }, {
    id: 4, name: 'Chilled Items', off: 'chilled', on: 'chilled_on',
  },
];

export default class Category extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return mCategories.map((mCategory) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={mCategory.id}
      >
        <Image
          source={require(`app/assets/ico/ico_category_${mCategory.on}.png`)}
        />
        <Text>{mCategory.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
  }
}
```

**Error**

> Invalid call at line 28: require("app/assets/ico/ico_category_" + mCategory.on + ".png")

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991669/react-native-require-with-dynamic-string?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have two option

1- create a file with image required - React native images must be loaded this way.

```
export const friendsandfoe = require('./image1.png'); 
export const lifeanddeath = require('./image2.png'); 
export const homeandgarden = require('./image3.png');
```

after that

```
import * as images from '../../assets';
```

and

```
<Image source={images[`${imageValue}`]}></Image>
```

=================================================================

2- use this syntax

```
<Image source={{uri: 'imagename'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
```

===========================================================================

Answer (score 0):

I should have made it like this at first.

This Worked!

```js
const mCategories = [
  {
    id: null,
    name: 'All',
    on: require('app/assets/ico/ico_category_all_on.png'),
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Whole Cakes',
    on: require('app/assets/ico/ico_category_wc_on.png'),
  },
];

export default class Category extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return mCategories.map((mCategory) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={mCategory.id}
      >
        <Image
          source={mCategory.on}
        />
        <Text>{mCategory.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
  }
}
```