# How to import multi images in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, require

I have something like this.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp1TM.png]

I want to import multi images with shorter code.

I tried to use a template string like this
[image]

But it seems to require not to show my image.

Comment: If your file is in public directory. You can access your image by using normal string. Try this, `style={{ backgroundImage : 'url(../../assets/images/forest/Layer_0002.png)'}} `

Comment: No my file is in src

Comment: The reason why the template string is not working: 
[react's require() only uses static url not variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991669/react-native-require-with-dynamic-string?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an index file to re-export all the images in folder

> assets/images/forest/index.js

```
import layer0001 from './Layer_0001.png';
import layer0002 from './Layer_0002.png';
import layer0003 from './Layer_0003.png';

export { layer0001, layer0002, layer0003 };
```

and importing them as named import

```
import { layer0001, layer0002, layer0003 } from 'assets/images/forest';
```

or import everything

```
import * as forest from 'assets/images/forest';
```

which allow you to do a dynamic URL like

```
let layer = 'layer001';

backgroundImage: `url(${forest[layer]})`
```